# How to have dynamically loaded instances of unbound named XAML elements behave independently from each other?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application where I dynamically load document view instances into a `TabControl`. The view has a `ToolBar` with some `ToggleButton`s which I use to control the visibility of certain elements in that view like so (only relevant elements shown):

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.View.Views.DocumentView" ...>
    ...
    <ToolBar>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="togglePropInspector" ... />
        ...
    </ToolBar>
    ...
    <Border Visibility={Binding ElementName=togglePropInspector, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        ...
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

I found this kinda neat as everything is handled inside the view and didn't require adding code to the view model (or code behind). However, the problem is that checking the toggle button on one tab now checks it in all instances of the view, not just the current tab. This basically applies to all elements whose state is not bound to the view model in any way. Is there a way around this without having to add code to the view model?

For completeness' sake here's the relevant part of how I'm loading the views:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:DocumentViewModel}">
            <local:DocumentView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: "*all instances of the view*" is actually a misconception. Instead of creating multiple instances of the DocumentView control, the TabControl only creates a single one and changes its DataContext when another Tab is selected. Maybe you can reset the control state in a DataContextChanged event handler. Otherwise store the state in the data item class.

Comment: Ah!! OK, that probably explains a lot (including the noticeable lag when switching between tabs of large documents)... If you post that as an answer I could definitely accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabControl` has a single content host that is used for all `TabItem` instances. When the data models assigned to the `TabItem.Content` property are of the same data type, then the `TabControl` will reuse the same `DataTemplate`, which means same element instances, only updated with the changed data from data bindings.

To change the state of the reused controls, you must either access the control explicitly, or force the `TabControl` to reapply the `ContentTemplate` by temporarily changing the data type of the `Content`:

```xml
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged" />
```

```cs
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var tabControl = sender as TabControl;
  var tabItemContainer = tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(tabControl.SelectedItem) as TabItem;
  object currentContent = tabItemContainer.Content;
  tabItemContainer.Content = null;

  // Defer and leave the context to allow the TabControl to handle the new data type (null).
  // The content switch shouldn't be noticable in the GUI.
  Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => tabItemContainer.Content = currentContent);
}
```

You can also use a dedicated data type for each tab. This way the `TabControl` is automatically forced to switch the `DataTemplate`.

The cleanest solution would be to bind the `ToggleButton` to the data model.